# Why Fedora is not asking for root password when using sudo su?

Tags: fedora, sudo

I need your help, I've set a root password using the command

```bsh
sudo passwd root
```

It says that the password has been set.

But when I exit root user and execute the command

```bsh
sudo su
```

It doesn't ask for the root password and it logs into root account.

Why Fedora is not asking me for a root password?

Answer (score 0):

When you first enter the password for `sudo`, the password will be cached for a short time to allow you to run additional sudo commands in the same terminal without re-entering it.

See `man sudo`:

> Security policies may support credential caching to allow the user to run sudo again for a period of time without requiring authentication.  By default, the sudoers policy caches credentials on a per-terminal basis for 15 minutes.